# how do I fetch the second level array values in JSON data using jQuery each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I would like to select a particular value using jquery each from the second and third level array. This is my JSON response looks like:

```
{
    "events": [{
        "id": 847843,
        "name": "Strasbourg IG at Limoges CSP",
        "timezone": "GMT",
        "timezoneOffset": 0,
        "time": 1401983400000,
        "timeUtc": "2014-06-05T18:50:00+00:00",
        "status": "live",
        "wpRef": "847843",
        "parentCategoryId": 22,
        "parentCategoryName": "Basketball",
        "categoryId": 7443,
        "categoryName": "French Championnat Pro A ",
        "racingEvent": null,
        "raceNumber": null,
        "marketCount": 3,
        "prefix": null,
        "nameSeparator": null,
        "markets": [{
            "id": 4943131,
            "primitiveType": 2,
            "primitiveName": "Head to Head",
            "typeId": 36,
            "name": "Head to Head",
            "marketDescription": "Select the winner of the match.",
            "marketRules": "Includes extra time.\r",
            "eventNotices": null,
            "autoHide": false,
            "status": "live",
            "bettingStatus": "enabled",
            "period": "Fulltime",
            "allowMultiple": true,
            "betInRunTime": 0,
            "track": null,
            "weather": null,
            "betTypes": [{
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Win",
                "finishingOrder": null,
                "products": []
            }],
            "selections": [{
                "id": 288481048,
                "betId": null,
                "eventId": null,
                "eventNumber": null,
                "eventName": null,
                "eventTime": null,
                "position": null,
                "name": "Strasbourg IG",
                "prefix": "",
                "mpId": 288481048,
                "marketPosition": null,
                "marketName": null,
                "marketTypeName": null,
                "marketSelectionId": null,
                "marketSelectionName": null,
                "categoryId": null,
                "categoryName": null,
                "parentCategoryId": null,
                "parentCategoryName": null,
                "maxBet": 0.00,
                "scratched": false,
                "winPrice": null,
                "placePrice": null,
                "finalWinPrice": null,
                "finalPlacePrice": null,
                "finalPrice": null,
                "prices": [{
                    "betTypeId": 1,
                    "betTypeName": "Win",
                    "productId": null,
                    "productName": null,
                    "precisePrice": 2.6,
                    "usPrice": "+160",
                    "value": 2.60
                }]
            }, {
                "id": 288481039,
                "betId": null,
                "eventId": null,
                "eventNumber": null,
                "eventName": null,
                "eventTime": null,
                "position": null,
                "name": "Limoges CSP",
                "prefix": "",
                "mpId": 288481039,
                "marketPosition": null,
                "marketName": null,
                "marketTypeName": null,
                "marketSelectionId": null,
                "marketSelectionName": null,
                "categoryId": null,
                "categoryName": null,
                "parentCategoryId": null,
                "parentCategoryName": null,
                "maxBet": 0.00,
                "scratched": false,
                "winPrice": null,
                "placePrice": null,
                "finalWinPrice": null,
                "finalPlacePrice": null,
                "finalPrice": null,
                "prices": [{
                    "betTypeId": 1,
                    "betTypeName": "Win",
                    "productId": null,
                    "productName": null,
                    "precisePrice": 1.44,
                    "usPrice": "-227",
                    "value": 1.44
                }]
            }]
        }, {
            "id": 4943134,
            "primitiveType": 99,
            "primitiveName": "Other",
            "typeId": 1266,
            "name": "Odd or Even Total",
            "marketDescription": "Select whether the amount of points scored in the match will be an odd or even number (zero = even)\r\rIncludes overtime.",
            "marketRules": "For this market zero will be deemed to be an even number.\r\rNo bonus bets.\r\rIncludes overtime.",
            "eventNotices": null,
            "autoHide": true,
            "status": "live",
            "bettingStatus": "enabled",
            "period": "Fulltime",
            "allowMultiple": true,
            "betInRunTime": 0,
            "track": null,
            "weather": null,
            "betTypes": [{
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Win",
                "finishingOrder": null,
                "products": []
            }],
            "selections": [{
                "id": 288481066,
                "betId": null,
                "eventId": null,
                "eventNumber": null,
                "eventName": null,
                "eventTime": null,
                "position": null,
                "name": "Even",
                "prefix": "",
                "mpId": 288481066,
                "marketPosition": null,
                "marketName": null,
                "marketTypeName": null,
                "marketSelectionId": null,
                "marketSelectionName": null,
                "categoryId": null,
                "categoryName": null,
                "parentCategoryId": null,
                "parentCategoryName": null,
                "maxBet": 0.00,
                "scratched": false,
                "winPrice": null,
                "placePrice": null,
                "finalWinPrice": null,
                "finalPlacePrice": null,
                "finalPrice": null,
                "prices": [{
                    "betTypeId": 1,
                    "betTypeName": "Win",
                    "productId": null,
                    "productName": null,
                    "precisePrice": 1.85,
                    "usPrice": "-118",
                    "value": 1.85
                }]
            }, {
                "id": 288481075,
                "betId": null,
                "eventId": null,
                "eventNumber": null,
                "eventName": null,
                "eventTime": null,
                "position": null,
                "name": "Odd",
                "prefix": "",
                "mpId": 288481075,
                "marketPosition": null,
                "marketName": null,
                "marketTypeName": null,
                "marketSelectionId": null,
                "marketSelectionName": null,
                "categoryId": null,
                "categoryName": null,
                "parentCategoryId": null,
                "parentCategoryName": null,
                "maxBet": 0.00,
                "scratched": false,
                "winPrice": null,
                "placePrice": null,
                "finalWinPrice": null,
                "finalPlacePrice": null,
                "finalPrice": null,
                "prices": [{
                    "betTypeId": 1,
                    "betTypeName": "Win",
                    "productId": null,
                    "productName": null,
                    "precisePrice": 1.85,
                    "usPrice": "-118",
                    "value": 1.85
                }]
            }]
        }, {
            "id": 4943137,
            "primitiveType": 99,
            "primitiveName": "Other",
            "typeId": 1298,
            "name": "Match Result",
            "marketDescription": null,
            "marketRules": null,
            "eventNotices": null,
            "autoHide": false,
            "status": "live",
            "bettingStatus": "enabled",
            "period": "Fulltime",
            "allowMultiple": true,
            "betInRunTime": 0,
            "track": null,
            "weather": null,
            "betTypes": [{
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Win",
                "finishingOrder": null,
                "products": []
            }],
            "selections": [{
                "id": 288481102,
                "betId": null,
                "eventId": null,
                "eventNumber": null,
                "eventName": null,
                "eventTime": null,
                "position": null,
                "name": "Strasbourg IG",
                "prefix": "",
                "mpId": 288481102,
                "marketPosition": null,
                "marketName": null,
                "marketTypeName": null,
                "marketSelectionId": null,
                "marketSelectionName": null,
                "categoryId": null,
                "categoryName": null,
                "parentCategoryId": null,
                "parentCategoryName": null,
                "maxBet": 0.00,
                "scratched": false,
                "winPrice": null,
                "placePrice": null,
                "finalWinPrice": null,
                "finalPlacePrice": null,
                "finalPrice": null,
                "prices": [{
                    "betTypeId": 1,
                    "betTypeName": "Win",
                    "productId": null,
                    "productName": null,
                    "precisePrice": 2.63,
                    "usPrice": "+163",
                    "value": 2.63
                }]
            }, {
                "id": 288481084,
                "betId": null,
                "eventId": null,
                "eventNumber": null,
                "eventName": null,
                "eventTime": null,
                "position": null,
                "name": "Limoges CSP",
                "prefix": "",
                "mpId": 288481084,
                "marketPosition": null,
                "marketName": null,
                "marketTypeName": null,
                "marketSelectionId": null,
                "marketSelectionName": null,
                "categoryId": null,
                "categoryName": null,
                "parentCategoryId": null,
                "parentCategoryName": null,
                "maxBet": 0.00,
                "scratched": false,
                "winPrice": null,
                "placePrice": null,
                "finalWinPrice": null,
                "finalPlacePrice": null,
                "finalPrice": null,
                "prices": [{
                    "betTypeId": 1,
                    "betTypeName": "Win",
                    "productId": null,
                    "productName": null,
                    "precisePrice": 1.5,
                    "usPrice": "-200",
                    "value": 1.50
                }]
            }, {
                "id": 288481093,
                "betId": null,
                "eventId": null,
                "eventNumber": null,
                "eventName": null,
                "eventTime": null,
                "position": null,
                "name": "Draw",
                "prefix": "",
                "mpId": 288481093,
                "marketPosition": null,
                "marketName": null,
                "marketTypeName": null,
                "marketSelectionId": null,
                "marketSelectionName": null,
                "categoryId": null,
                "categoryName": null,
                "parentCategoryId": null,
                "parentCategoryName": null,
                "maxBet": 0.00,
                "scratched": false,
                "winPrice": null,
                "placePrice": null,
                "finalWinPrice": null,
                "finalPlacePrice": null,
                "finalPrice": null,
                "prices": [{
                    "betTypeId": 1,
                    "betTypeName": "Win",
                    "productId": null,
                    "productName": null,
                    "precisePrice": 13.00,
                    "usPrice": "+1200",
                    "value": 13.00
                }]
            }]
        }],
        "result": null
    }]
}
```

I am able to fetch all the "name" field from events category using the below code.

```
drawAllEvents: function (events)  {
    var $container = $('#someID ul');
    $.each(events, function(i, event) {
        $('<a />', { text: event.name, href: '#' }).wrap('<li />').parent().appendTo($container);
    });
}
```

Now I am trying to fetch "primitiveName" field from the markets array using another function but for some reason it returns undefined. Here is my code

```
drawAllBetTypesFilter: function (events)  {
    $('#bettype-sport ul').empty();
    var betTypeFilter = $('#bettype-sport ul');
    $.each(events, function (i, event) {
        $.each(event.markets, function (market) {
            var betTypeName = market.primitiveName;
            $('<a />', {
                text: betTypeName
            }).wrap('<li />').parent().appendTo(betTypeFilter);
        });
    });
}
```

Furthermore, How do I fetch third level array, for e.g If I want to fetch all "name" fields under "betTypes" which is a child of "markets" object.

EDIT: 1 - Also mentioned in my comment. How do I group similar `primitiveName` values together in my list instead of displaying them seperately.

Here is the fiddle to show how am I fetching values in first level. [FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/7EYUB/2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first parameter passed to the `each()` iteration function is the index of the current element in the array, so in your current code your `market` parameter is not the element from the array but instead an int. Try this:

```
var betTypeFilter = $('#bettype-sport ul');
$.each(events, function (i, event) {
    $.each(event.markets, function (i, market) { // <- note 'i' first param
        var betTypeName = market.primitiveName;
        $('<a />', {
            text: betTypeName
        }).wrap('<li />').parent().appendTo(betTypeFilter);

        // to get betTypes for this market:
        $.each(market.betTypes, function(i, betType) {
            // do something...
            console.log(betType);
        });
    });
});
```

To fetch the `name` under `betTypes` would take another loop. Or, if there is only ever one object in the array you could hard-code access to the first element only:

```
market.betTypes[0].name; // == 'Win'
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes I missed looping the index, it works now. Could you please 2 more doubts. 1) As you can see in the JSON, there are 2 similar primitiveName returned from the JSON response. How do I group them together and instead of displaying them seperately in a list I would prefer to show something like "Other (2)" Second question: if there are more objects in the third level array the each loop would look like $.each(event.markets.betTypes, function (i, betTypes) ??

Comment: 1) I'm not sure what you mean? I guess you're after some kind of expanding element that shows more detail on click? If so, I'd start a new question for that. 2) No, it would need to be tied to a specific market, so inside the `each()` for `event.markets`: `$.each(market.betTypes, function(i, betType)`. I added an example to my answer.

Comment: I am not looking for addition details on click event. As you can see in this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/7EYUB/3/) I am displaying "other" twice since I have same parameter name in the JSON. I would like to group them together, so instead of printing "other" twice I would simply display like "other (2)"

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, instead of using the jquery each function, why not just use traditional javascript looping.  The $.each method isn't nearly as efficient as that.

```
drawAllBetTypesFilter: function (events)  {
    $('#bettype-sport ul').empty();
    var betTypeFilter = $('#bettype-sport ul');
    for(var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        var event = events[i];
        for(var j = 0; j < event.markets.length; j++) {
            var market = event.markets[j];
            var betTypeName = market.primitiveName;
            $('<a />', {
                text: betTypeName
            }).wrap('<li />').parent().appendTo(betTypeFilter);
        };
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you shed some light on the comment I posted above and the edit I made in my question.

Comment: If you are looking to group items with a similar primitive name you need a function that can determine what the group.  For example, are you going merge bet types, selections, prices so that all the content from each record are stored together?  I did something similar with grades for a school district.  For them, I found once I had displayed the class once, ignore the rest.  I used a dictionary to check to see if I had visited a class or not.

Comment: In another part of the application, they wanted to merge an array of attendance items based on the class.  In the end, I looped through the data first to structure the data into something meaningful for the interface.

Comment: Yes I am looking something like that. But instead of ignoring  the rest as you mentioned in your comment I want to display them as a group. So for e.g. If I have 3 similar names in the JSON (lets say 'ABC') I would like to display them as ABC (3)

Comment: Ok, so what you can do is create a new javascript object array and do the calculation.  Everytime you find a matching name you could do one of two things.  When creating each new object it could have either a sub array of the items found, so you would then need to get the length of that array which would return 3 and preserve the content for access.  Alternatively, you could just add a counter property that counts everytime that name is found and increments on the new object.